# How to get maven compiler plugin to work without failing with tools.jar not found error?

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin, tools.jar

We are having some problems using maven under a strange unix-ish dev platform.  The maven compiler plugin complains about not being able to find the `tools.jar` due to weird JDK/JRE confusion in the default installed java.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:
      2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project xyz: Fatal error compiling:
      tools.jar not found: our-java-home-dir/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

The `../lib/tools.jar` should really be `lib/tools.jar`.    The java installation (Java 7) seems to be a JDK but somehow java is detecting it as only a JRE, hence the confusion.  In looking at what the java code is doing, it must be thinking that we have a JRE installation and is expecting `JAVA_HOME` to be pointing to the `jre` subdir of the real `JAVA_HOME`.  No amount of copying, symlinking, or other hackery seemed to work for us to get `../lib` to be the same as `lib`.

We've seen a lot of similar questions on the intertubes but none were of much help.  We were not able to reinstall Java or any solution like you would do on other platforms but it is supposed to be a full JDK and includes all of the j*tools down in the `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: Which java version do you use?

Comment: We are using java 7.

Comment: The usage of tools.jar must be done somewhere manually..check your pom files...Furthermore I would recommend to upgrade your plugin version...

Comment: `tools.jar` is needed by the maven compiler plugin @khmarbaise.  It compiles stuff.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... tools.jar not found: our-java-home-dir/../lib/tools.jar -> [Help 1]

One solution for us that seems to work was is to the force the `tools.jar` file onto the boot-class-path of the maven command by hand.  We used the following program to dump the current value of the boot-class-path:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Boot-class-path=" +
            System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path"));
    }
}
```

Then we modified the end of the mvn script in `$M2_HOME/bin/mvn` to insert the `-Xbootclasspath` option:

```sh
$MAVEN_OPTS \
    -Xbootclasspath:existing-boot-class-path-here:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar \
    -additional-maven-options-go-here...
```

We added the `tools.jar` entry to the end of the value spat out by the main program above.  There are other maven options that you need to leave in there of course.

Hope this helps someone else.